# Nginx 403 for newly created files

Tags: django, nginx

My Django app is configured nginx. Media files are served by nginx directly. The issue I have now is that nginx is giving 403 forbidden for the pdf files i uploaded.  Pdf files are uploaded to media/file directory. When i do

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data media/file
```

The file will be loaded. But when i upload another pdf, nginx is again returning 403.  I have also tried

```
sudo chmod g+s media/file
```

That also did not work. So each time i have to run chown to make the file load.

This is happening only for big files. Files having size less than 1MB is working fine. Permissions are correctly set. But when files having size greater than 1 MB is uploaded the permission is changed. For bigger files only ubuntu group(Default user in aws) is having permission. For small files it is fine, www-data is having the permission.

Comment: Have django set the file permissions when they're uploaded?

Comment: www-data is not having permission for the new files uploaded. Only ubuntu user (default user in amazon instance) is having permission.

Comment: Run nginx and django both with the same user, and assign that user owenership of that directory.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution that worked for me was setting FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS is Django like below

> FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o644

There could be a more cleaner method.